# How to set a condition for Twilio TwiML Bin so call is only redirected if not answered via timeout?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

For reference, here is my current TwiML Bin which forwards my call (using a whisper) and is set to redirect back to my studio flow for further handling (voicemail).

The problem I am running into is that even if the call is answered, the code executes a redirect back to my Studio. Which means if I hang up the call, it will continue my studio flow (i.e. caller will hear my voicemail flow right after I hang up).

So how would I add a condition to my TwiML Bin, which only redirects the call IF it times out?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial timeout="16">
<Number url="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/whisper">mynumber</Number>
</Dial>
  <Redirect>https://webhooks.twilio.com/url/?FlowEvent=return</Redirect>
</Response>
```